# Kibana Error : The aggregations key is missing from the response, check your permissions for this request

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am not much familiar with ELK stack. We monitor a particular server health using ELK stack. We have Metricbeat which sends statics and based on that we have index created in Elastic. Kibana visualization is created based on this. But from last couple of days we get below error in Kibana.
[Error Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOkJg.jpg)

Observations :

1. We validated Index Management to check if we have data. We could find that there is no issue in streaming as we continue to receive data. 
   [Index Management Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjFC4.png)
2. When tried to view the index from Discover, got below Request Timeout Error.
   [Discover Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97iaK.jpg)
3. Any query we run in Dev Tools returns Internal Server Error, as like below.
   [Dev Tools Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4tsb.jpg)

We have ELK setup in dockerised env, ie, seperate docker for Elastic, Logstash and Kibana. When I restart the Kibana container alone, Kibana is back normal. But after sometime, I get this error again.

What could be the reason. We are stuck with this for sometime and did not get any valid leads.
Thanks in advance